# How to send a user a DM from a bot and catch the response via Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This may be a stupid question but I really need this figured out. I'm working on having an interface between my bot and DM channels. My current code is:

```
if input.startswith('.direct'):
    content = re.sub(r'^\W*\w+\W*', '', message.content)
    await client.send_message(discord.PrivateChannel(User ID), content)
```

This basically tries to send a message via User ID, but doesn't work. I've checked the API several times, and can't figure it out. I don't want message.author or anything like that. I need to be able to message a user based on their tag or User ID. Any help appreciated, and for bonus points, how to catch the response as well?

Answer (score 3):

Get their user object from the id, then use `client.send_message(destination, content)` to send the message to them. You can do this in one line since `client.get_user_info(id)` (returns user object from ID) is also a coroutine.

```
if input.startswith('.direct'):
    content = re.sub(r'^\W*\w+\W*', '', message.content)
    await client.send_message(client.get_user_info(id), content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
@client.command(description="send prv messege (only admins)") 
async def dm(ctx, member:discord.User=None, text =None):
 try:
    if (text == None):
        await ctx.channel.send("You  have to write a text!")
        return
    if (member == ctx.message.author or member == None):
        await ctx.send("""You cannot DM yourself!""") 

    message = f"You have been dmed from {ctx.guild.name} for {text}"
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is dmed!")
 except:
    await ctx.send(f"Error dming user {member} (cannot dm owner or bot)")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64951715/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Have yout tired using:

```
client.start_private_message(user)
```

?